# mysql-Workbench can't connect to server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In workbench the status of the server is STOPPED and the startup log message:

```
2016-05-28 11:14:37 - Checking server status...
2016-05-28 11:14:37 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2016-05-28 11:14:37 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) (2003)
2016-05-28 11:14:37 - Assuming server is not running
```

When I run:

```
sudo service mysql status
```

I get:

```
mysql start/post-start, process 3061
post-start process 3062
```

Could anybody help?

Comment: Checking the status after a few minutes it changed to: mysql stop/waiting

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` does not have `bind-address` set, then restart the server. This will allow connections from localhost.

Comment: I commented out the bind-address option and now I get this:

Comment: well, the log is too long to post.  there an error though:     [ERROR]  /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp'
    2016-05-28 14:48:08    [ERROR]  Aborting

Comment: Can you upload your `my.cnf` to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ please?

Comment: OK, just did (I hope)

Comment: What's the link?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16780361/

Comment: In the place that you have `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` I have `skip-external-locking`. Try either commenting that line. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701636/how-to-enable-explicit-defaults-for-timestamp

Comment: Also posted the Error log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16780493/

Comment: The Startup Message Log is changing and getting longer. http://paste.ubuntu.com/16780638/

Comment: Did you restart the actual mysql process, not just the workbench?

Comment: I actually restarted the whole server.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what the issue is, as the log doesn't actually provide an error.

Comment: one more try. Though I commented out the "bind-address" line it is still "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) (2003)".

Comment: That's because the server won't start, it is shutting down, but it isn't providing an error message.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible issues:

- Make sure the service is really up and running: `netstat -plnt | grep mysql`
- make sure it is on the address:port you expect it to see, for examlpe here you won't be able to connect from outside because the only IP with MySQL is localhost: 
  `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      12460/mysqld`. If you don't see it here but see in the processes (`ps -eF | grep mysqld`) then perhaps it is bound to socket only.
- make sure the process is alive by logging in from console: `mysql -u user -p`
- make sure the firewall(s) allow(s) your remote host to connect to the server to that port (e.g. [nmap](http://nmap.org/download.html), windows version available too)
- make sure there's no typo in workbench connection settings.